# interesting page styles

Tags: webpage, styles

i'm searching for page styles for pleasant look and feel for my page(content,layout,image organisation,article placement...). where do i get it. can you guide me with someone.

Comment: Given the subjective nature of the question?.. this should probably be a Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/03/26/grid-based-design-six-creative-column-techniques/) on grid-based layout and design. It's kind of old, but it's a good start if you're interested in learning about a design concept, with the view to coming up with your own.

Looking through the rest of the [Smashing Magazine Showcases](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/showcases/) may provide further inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.oswd.org/

http://www.openwebdesign.org/browse.php